# Standardized Regression Time Series

Tags: r, time-series, regression

My model is as the following:

y = beta0 * exp(beta1 * t) + z

Where

t: time

z: time series model

Q1: My question is should I standardized the independent variable time, t?

Q2: Is the standard deviation that I got from my code called empirical standard deviation?

R CODE:

```
library(forecast)
set.seed(100)
nsim=1000

#####################################
output.df <-data.frame(
    N=integer(),
    mu1=double(),
    mu2=double()
)
N <- c(50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, 2000) # sample size

SimulateAR2 <- function(N,nsim){
    phi=0.2
    alpha <- 20
    beta <- -0.05
    for (n in N) {
        t=ts(1:n)
        t=(t-mean(t))/sd(t)
        for (i in 1: nsim) {
            w <- rnorm(n,0,1)
            z<-unclass(arima.sim(model=list(ar=phi),n=n,innov=w))
            y =alpha*exp(beta*t) + z
            fit <- nls(
                y~ alpha*exp(beta*t),
                start = list(alpha=alpha,beta= beta ), 
                control= nls.control(
                    maxiter = 50, 
                    tol = 1e-05, 
                    minFactor = 1/1024, 
                    printEval = FALSE, 
                    warnOnly = T
                )
            )
            mean = coef(fit)
            names(mean) = c( "mu1", "mu2")
            output.df <- rbind(output.df, cbind(N=n,t(c(mean))))
        }
    }
    return(output.df)
}

#the entire data set
output.df <- as.data.frame(SimulateAR2(N, nsim))
str(output.df)
table(output.df$N)

#the sample mean
round(aggregate(output.df[,2:3], list(output.df$N), mean),4)

#empirical standard deviation
round(aggregate(output.df[,2:3], list(output.df$N), sd),4)
```

OUTPUT:

```
> round(aggregate(output.df[,2:3], list(output.df$N), mean),4)
  Group.1     mu1     mu2
1      50 19.9974 -0.0499
2     100 20.0060 -0.0497
3     200 20.0007 -0.0500
4     500 20.0027 -0.0501
5    1000 19.9988 -0.0500
6    2000 19.9991 -0.0499

> round(aggregate(output.df[,2:3], list(output.df$N), sd),4)
 Group.1    mu1    mu2
1      50 0.1773 0.0090
2     100 0.1286 0.0064
3     200 0.0893 0.0045
4     500 0.0563 0.0026
5    1000 0.0393 0.0020
6    2000 0.0281 0.0013
```